# Issue parsing DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following string `2023-07-18 11:38 AM`

I'm trying to parse it using the  following code to parse the same

```
fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(adhocData.FromDateTime, 
                               "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm tt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

But i keep getting the following error

> String '2023-07-18 11:38 AM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: You talk about formatting but post *parsing* code. DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. What is `adhocData.FromDateTime`, where did it come from? Why is it *not* a DateTime or DateTimeOffset but a string?

Comment: As you posted the error as JSON, I suspect you're building a web app and returned part of the exception as a JSON string (not helpful). Dates in JSON are in ISO8601 format and that sting isn't in that format. Either the API is using custom formats (bad idea) or the actual DateTime value was formatted as a string with a localized format (also bad idea)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The date is formatted to a string from the frontend and passed back to the c# backend.

Comment: The frontend has a bug that must be fixed then. The [RFC-7943](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3) standard specifies that dates should be in ISO8601, and that string isn't in that format. `AM/PM` aren't part of the standard. ASP.NET Core automatically maps ISO8601 to DateTime. JavaScript's `toJSON()` generates an ISO8601 string too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In the front end we are using react typescript. A moment object is used and it is converted to a string like this `apiFromDateTime?.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a')`. Why do you think this is a bug, we are doing the same formatting in the backend.

Comment: Don't use the display strings in your API calls. Use the `Date` objects. `fetch` works fine with objects, why deal with strings?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay.. We are using a moment object `const [apiFromDateTime, setapiFromDateTime] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(moment());` how we post it to the c# controller ?

Comment: [moment objects are serialized to ISO8601](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/13-as-json/) out of the box when `JSON.stringify` is used. The comment doesn't show how you post but in the [MDN's POST JSON example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data) `fetch` is used with `body: JSON.stringify(data)`. Any `Date` or `moment` properties will be serialized correctly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos JSON.stringify is used.I will do it , thanks a lot for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is slightly wrong, try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2023-07-18 11:38 AM", 
                    "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note the caps of the year and day component!

Answer (score 3):

Use the string format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt" instead of "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm tt".

This fixed the problem and even the time is displaying properly.

[see the program here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp38V.png)

Comment: Please post the *text* of your code, not as image

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to ensure ISO8601 is sent from the client. From the comments, the string is generated in a React application using moment with `apiFromDateTime?.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a')`. There's no need for this.

`moment` objects are [serialized to ISO8601 out of the box though](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/13-as-json/). The documentation example shows how an object containing a `moment` object gets serialized to JSON:

```
JSON.stringify({
    postDate : moment()
});
```

This produces

```
'{"postDate":"2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z"}'
```

POSTing this to the server with `fetch` should just work. Borrowing [MDN's fetch example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data) :

```
const data={
    postDate : moment()
}

const response = await fetch("https://example.com/profile", {
      method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
```